# How do I use a map with a multi class template

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

I need help creating a standard library c++ map.  The code I have to work with looks like this.

```
    template<class Key, class Type>


    public:
      STLMap(){
         //constructor goes here
      }
```

I know how to make a map using a template that has just one class, but I have no idea how to do it with two.  In this case each, the Key and Type are the key and type I need to use with the map.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `Key` and `Type` as real types, and when the template is used, the real types will be used. `std::map<Key, Type>` for `STLMap<int, char>` will become `std::map<int, char>`.

```
template<class Key, class Type>
class STLMap
{
  public:
    STLMap()
    {
    }

  private:
    std::map<Key, Type> _map;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  one issue I have is that now I'm getting "error: 'map' in namespace 'std' does not name a type"  Ring any bells?

Comment: I have figured out my secondary problem; I forgot to #include <map>.